# Excel file downloadeb by google chrome

Tags: django, excel, google-chrome

I have request which download excel file! And some texts into cell very big, and I am trying to divide it into several lines. And I am using xlwt in django: this is my code:

```
def parse_string(label=""):
if len(label) == 0:
    return "", 1
t = ""
mx_sym = 50
endl = 0
for i in label:
    if mx_sym > 0:
        t += i
        mx_sym -= 1
    elif mx_sym <= 0 and i != ' ':
        t += i
    elif mx_sym <= 0 and i == ' ':
        t += "\n"
        endl += 1
        mx_sym = 50
return t, endl
```

this is my function to divide text into several lines

```
def single_doc_report_to_xls(file, report):
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet(u'Отчет #')
al = xlwt.Alignment()
al.wrap = xlwt.Alignment.WRAP_AT_RIGHT

ws.write(0, 0, u"№ п/п")
ws.write(0, 1, u"Наименование документа")
ws.write(0, 2, u"Наличие документа")
ws.write(0, 3, u"Дата вложения документа")
ws.write(0, 4, u"Дата приема документа сотрудником ЦПМБ/ЦПСБ")
ws.write(0, 5, u"Комментарии по документу (при наличии)")
ws.write(0, 6, u"Статус документа (в обработке/ на доработке/ принят Банком для рассмотрения)")

ws.col(0).width = 256 * 60
ws.col(1).width = 256 * 65
ws.col(2).width = 256 * 60
ws.col(3).width = 256 * 20
ws.col(4).width = 256 * 60
ws.col(5).width = 256 * 60
ws.col(6).width = 256 * 60


index = 1
for r in report:
    ws.write(index, 0, r["num"])
    cur_mx = 1

    t, h = parse_string(r["description"])
    cur_mx = max(cur_mx, h)
    ws.write(index, 1, t)

    t, h = parse_string(r["has_file"])
    cur_mx = max(cur_mx, h)
    ws.write(index, 2, t)

    t, h = parse_string(r["create_timestamp"])
    cur_mx = max(cur_mx, h)
    ws.write(index, 3, t)

    t, h = parse_string(r["status_timestamp"])
    cur_mx = max(cur_mx, h)
    ws.write(index, 4, t)

    t, h = parse_string(r["comments"])
    cur_mx = max(cur_mx, h)
    ws.write(index, 5, t)

    t, h = parse_string(r["status_display"])
    cur_mx = max(cur_mx, h)
    ws.write(index, 6, t)

    ws.row(index).height_mismatch = True
    ws.row(index).height = 256 * max(3, cur_mx*2)
    index += 1

wb.save(file)
```

above function to write data into excel, and everything works correctly when I download excel by mozilla, but for google chtore it does'nt work. And I don't know why. Please, help me.

this is excel file which download by mozilla
[image]

and this one by google chrome:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a Django question.

The files appear to be the same, but have different text wrapping applied to the cells (although my Cyrillic is v shakey).

The top one has opened using Excel that is auto wrapping inside the cell.  The latter, from Chrome, *appears* to be opening in Google Sheets or similar, with auto wrap turned off, although it's hard to tell with the way you've cropped the image.  If you go into your downloads folders and open both with Excel, you should see the same thing.  Your wrap is set in the file generation, but individual browsers and spreadsheet programmes can override with their local settings.